# How to store date value into database from date picker by using Input(text) control

Tags: c#, sql-server, input

I am trying to store date into database using Input(text) control/ jQueryUI , because there is no datetimepicker in my toolbox in Visual Studio 2017. My HTML code as below:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
 <script>
     $( function() {
         $("#datepicker").datepicker();
     });
 </script>

<input id="datepicker" class="auto-style7" type="text" />
```

From my C# code, I think the problem is here:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ApplyDate", datepicker.Value.Date);
```

`datepicker.Value.Date` said that datepicker does not exist in this context. How can I fix it?

Comment: *datepicker.Value.Date is wrong* - "wrong" how?? Define more clearly **what** you're expecting, and **what** you're actually seeing instead.....

Comment: @Conard put the runat = "server" and remove replace datepicker.Value.Date to datepicker.Value and cast it if your parameter have date type.

Comment: @marc_s It said datepicker does not exist in current context

Comment: Actually I am using JQueryUI library to make the Input(text) control as a datepicker to let users select date. However, the textbox can store value into database like this `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBoxPass.Text);` . But I don't know how to do with the datepicker